# Format email Date into "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I'm trying to format the date of an email using python2.7. The value of date is like

```
Date: "Tue, 9 Apr 2019 11:49:26 -0400"
```

Here's the code:

```
"date": datetime.strptime(d_items['Date'], '%a,%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

While stripping the timezone and formatting I'm getting the below error using datetime.datetime function.

```
'z' is a bad directive in format '%a,%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
```

Is there any other way to get the format like below:

```
2019-04-09 11:49:26
```

Comment: Where is code that you have used for *stripping the timezone and formatting*?

Comment: I got the solution using dateutil.parser.parse() which was not supported in datetime.strptime()